# Semialgebra logical error

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I was following a proof on Rosenthal's, A first look at rigorous probability theory book, but I believe that one step flawed. Let me set up:

$\mathcal{J}$ is a semialgebra of subsets of $\Omega$. Meaning that:

1. $\emptyset, \Omega \in \mathcal{J}$.
2. $\mathcal{J}$ is closed under intersections.
3. If $A \in \mathcal{J}$ then $A^C$ is a finite disjoint union of elements of $\mathcal{J}$.

Then let $\{A_i\}$ be a countable family of elements of $\mathcal{J}$ such that $\bigcup_i A_i \in \mathcal{J}$. For the purpose of the proof, he need a disjoint family to apply Additivity, hence he construct a family $\{D_i\}$ with $D_1 = A_1$ and
$$ D_n = A_n - \left( \bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}A_i\right) = A_n \cap \left( \bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1}A_i^C\right)$$

Now by construction $\{D_i\}$ are disjoint and $\bigcup_i D_i = \bigcup_i A_1$.
So far I got it, but then he says:

> Furthermore, since $\mathcal{J}$ is a semialgebra, each $D_n$ can be written as a finite disjoint union of elements of $\mathcal{J}$.

For that to apply, $D_n^C$ have to be in $\mathcal{J}$, but that does not seem to be the case, as
$$ D_n^C = \left( A_n \cap \left( \bigcap_{i=1}^{n-1}A_i^C\right) \right)^C$$
$$ = A_n^C \cup \left( \bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}A_i\right) $$

As $A_i \in \mathcal{J}$, the closest that I got is that $D_i^C$ is a finite union of elements of $\mathcal{J}$, but as a semialgebra may not be closed under unions. It's not clear to me that $D_n^C$ is in $\mathcal{J}$ so $(D_n^C)^C = D_n$ can be written as a finite disjoint union in $\mathcal{J}$.

Any light in whether I'm missing something or if his reasoning is really flawed or not will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that, if $A$ is a disjoint union of $m$ elements of $\mathcal J$, and if $B$ is a disjoint union of $n$ elements of $\mathcal J$, then $A\cap B$ is a disjoint union of at most $mn$ elements of $\mathcal J$; this is because $\mathcal J$ is closed under finite intersection.,

Now observe that the set $D_n$ is the intersection of the $n$ sets $A_1^C,A_2^C,\dots,A_{n-1}^C,A_n$, and that each of those sets is a finite disjoint union of elements of $\mathcal J$. It follows that $D_n$ is a finite disjoint union of elements of $\mathcal J$.

Comment: Well, interesting, I'll try to make a formal proof in this direction, although it'll likely get very tedious.

Comment: @victorsouza A formal proof can be found on page 134 of *Infinite Dimensional Analysis* by Aliprantis & Border, 2006.

Comment: On this book he proves for a semiring, but I believe one can adapt the proof.